# Different inference time for same PyTorch model, trained on different data

Tags: performance, pytorch

This is a more general question and I am wondering if anyone has experienced this and can suggest possible explanations:

I have two (.pkl) instances of the same torch model, trained on two different datasets. Inference time of one model is however considerably higher than the other one (X15). Any suggestions as to how this could be happening?

Comment: Have you checked the device of the models? Do they both use the same device (GPU or CPU)?

Comment: Environment + GPU are all the same. I ran both models on another machine (M2) (identical GPU + environment to the other machine (M1)) and it works as expected! However on M1, one model takes drastically longer than the other!